# В базу данный отправляется пустое значение, вместо значения из формы

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Есть простенький чатик на php/ajax/mysql. Но к сожалению, при отправке формы, в базу данных заносится пустая строка, в чём может быть проблема ?

Вот файл с формой, page.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#messages").load('ajaxLoad.php');



  $("#userArea").submit(function(){
    $.post('ajaxPost.php', $('#userArea').serialize(), function(data){
        $("#messages").append('<div>'+data+'</div>');
        
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div id="messages"></div>
    <form method="post" action="ajaxPost.php" id="userArea" style="margin: 0 auto; font-size: 23px; text-align: center;">
      <h1>Чат</h1>
      <input type="text" name="message" />
      <input type="submit" value="ответить !" />
    </form>    
</div>
<?php include_once('ajaxLoad.php'); ?>
<?php include_once('ajaxPost.php'); ?>
```

Файл который работает с формой ajaxPost.php:

```
<?php 
include_once('page.php');
include('config.php');

$message = $_POST['message'];

$db->Query("INSERT INTO messages(message1) VALUES ('$message')");

echo $message;
?>
```

Comment: а в доме появляется сообщение после append ?

Comment: Да. Появляется пустой <div>. А в базу заносится новая ячейка с id, но с пустым полем 'message'.

Comment: а посмотрите через алерт, что у вас в $('#userArea').serialize() перед тем как отправлять

Comment: чудеса да и только

Comment: Ой. это если чекбокс. А вот если текст, то : 
message = 123
где 123 - это введённый текст.